# Convert Excel to datatable without using Connection String?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, infragistics

Is there a way to convert an excel file into a datatable (without using connection string), so i can show it in a gridview? I already tried something, but I'm getting a System.NullReferenceException and i don't know why. Here's what i did:

```
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        If File.Exists(OpenFileDialog1.FileName) Then
            If Path.GetExtension(OpenFileDialog1.FileName).ToString = ".xlsx" Then
                Dim workbook As Workbook

                Dim resourceName As String = "IGExcel.Resources." & OpenFileDialog1.FileName
                Using stream As Stream = Me.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)
                    Try
                        Workbook.Load(stream)

                    Catch ex As System.NullReferenceException

                    End Try
                End Using

                Dim dataTable As New DataTable
                Dim sheet As Worksheet = workbook.Worksheets(0)
                Dim serviceExcel
                For Each row As WorksheetRow In sheet.Rows
                    serviceExcel = New ISAACServiceExcel()
                    serviceExcel.AufPos = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
                    serviceExcel.UANR = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
                    serviceExcel.K_Art = row.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
                    serviceExcel.Ueberbegriff = row.Cells(3).Value.ToString()
                    serviceExcel.Benennung = row.Cells(5).Value.ToString()
                    serviceExcel.Einheit = row.Cells(6).Value.ToString()
                    serviceExcel.Einzelkosten = row.Cells(7).ToString()
                    serviceExcel.Anzahl = row.Cells(8).ToString()
                    serviceExcel.Komponente = row.Cells(9).ToString()
                    serviceExcel.Projektbeteiligter = row.Cells(11).ToString()
                    serviceExcel.Chefblattposition = row.Cells(13).ToString()
                    serviceExcel.Total = row.Cells(15).ToString()
                Next
                dataTable = serviceExcel
                dgv1.DataSource = dataTable
```

Comment: Which line did you get the NullReferenceException on?

Comment: Workbook.load(stream)

Comment: The line with the `Stream` constructor looks weird to me. Maybe you should replace with `Using stream As New FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)` ?

Comment: Now i get a NullReferenceException on 'Dim sheet As Worksheet = workbook.Worksheets(0)'

Comment: What have you got against connection strings?

Comment: Don't write empty Catch blocks. They swallow errors.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to convince you that there is nothing to fear from connection strings. Three little functions here and you are displaying your data. I would bet it is somewhat faster than interop also.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim XLPath = GetExcelPath()
    If XLPath IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim XLSheet = GetSheetName(XLPath)
        Dim dt = ExcelToDataTable(XLPath, XLSheet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No acceptable file selected.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetExcelPath() As String
    Dim XLPath As String
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        XLPath = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Return XLPath
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function

Private Function GetSheetName(path As String) As String
    Dim sn As String
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection($"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= {path};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';")
        cn.Open()
        dt = cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
    End Using
    sn = dt(0)("Table_Name").ToString
    Return sn
End Function

Private Function ExcelToDataTable(path As String, SheetName As String) As DataTable
    Dim XLConStr = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= {path};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(XLConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand($"Select * From [{SheetName}];", cn)
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```